# How do I set a dynamic array size in execution time?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm removing duplicated strings from an array and I'm pretty sure I need to use the Redim statement to dynamically change the size of the array, but I can't get it to work right.

Here's what I tried:

```
Dim temp() as String
Dim vetOrg as Variant

vetOrg = Array(contRows)
ReDim vetOrg(1 To contRows)


'populates the array
For i = 1 To contRows
    vetOrg(i) = wsDeals.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
Next i


 j = 1
    For i = 1 To contRows
        ReDim temp(1 To j)
        If vetOrg(i) <> vetOrg(i + 1) Then
            temp(j = j + 1) = vetOrg(i)
        End If
        temp(j = j + 1) = vetOrg(contRows - 1)
    Next i
```

Comment: if you want to keep the values in the array, you need to use `redim preserve` ... otherwise please detail what you think is not working. also `temp(j = j + 1)` wont work... make `j = j +1` before that and then do `temp(j)`.

Comment: maybe interest https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215646/vba-array-functions-push-pop-shift-unshift

Comment: You want to use a `Dictionary` instead; dictionary keys are inherently unique, and I'm pretty sure it's a O(1) hash lookup to determine whether a key exists - compared to O(n) for every element you lookup in an array. You'll want to reference the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `Scripting.Dictionary` you don't need to worry about resizing or searching for duplicate values; dictionary keys are inherently unique:

```
Dim vetOrg As Scripting.Dictionary
Set vetOrg = New Scripting.Dictionary

For i = 1 To contRows
    vetOrg(wsDeals.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value) = i ' value is bogus, it's the key we want.
Next i

'done. vetOrg.Keys has the unique values.
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but how do I `debug.print` this array? Since now I don't know its size. I tried `LBound(vetOrg) - UBound(vetOrg)` but it do not seems to work.

Comment: @Daniel you can't print *an array*, you need to iterate it and print *its elements*.